# AngularJS + Angular Strap - How to add dynamic content to modals depending on button clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, angularjs-directive

There is a working [jsfiddle that shows table + modal by using AngularJS + AngularStrap](http://jsfiddle.net/by3rph5s/5/q) (please see external resources in jsFiddle or take a look here for angular-strap  modals http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/modals)

**My question is**: How to add more dynamic to the buttons? They show static content, right? I need it to show the content of the first column (first name) of **exactly the same raw where the button was clicked**.
What's the best way to do that?

Also, the problem is that the rows of the table can be sorted by any column asc or desc so I don't think I can use id attributes.

Any ideas?

And here is the code:
HTML code:

```
<div  ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">
    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="person in persons">
            <td>{{ person.firstName }}</td>
            <td>{{ person.lastName }}</td>
            <td>{{ person.age }}</td>
            <td>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open()" bs-modal="modal"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

js code:

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('myApp', ['mgcrea.ngStrap']);


app.controller('ModalDemoCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.modal = {
  "title": "only one name of Manuela or Mark or Jane should be displayed here",
  "content": "only one name of Manuela or Mark or Jane should be displayed here"
};

    $scope.persons = [
        {
            "firstName": "Manuela",
            "lastName": "Smith",
            "age": 44
        },
        {
            "firstName": "Mark",
            "lastName": "Johnson",
            "age": 25
        },
        {
            "firstName": "Jane",
            "lastName": "Doe",
            "age": 33
        }
    ];

});
```

Thank you.

Comment: If you have the click trigger open(person) it will return the complete object displayed in the row. Then you can change the $scope.modal. Am I getting this wrong?

Comment: @Sphaso You mean I missed kind of this code inside the controller  $scope.open = function (){alert('one of buttons was clicked!'); console.log($scope);  }
However, the button of what raw was clicked, how to now? I don't see anything in scope that would help me to get that info.

Comment: Not really. In the HTML you have ng-click="open()". Change it into ng-click="open(person)". Then in the controller have your open function take the parameter. Et voilà. I'm still not 100% sure this is what you're after, but if you confirm I'll make it an answer.

Comment: Thank you, I think I did that with your help. Is that  the way to go? http://jsfiddle.net/by3rph5s/10/

Comment: Yes! Great job. I remember I had this same problem starting out with AngularJS :)

Comment: @Sphaso You've made my day. Your comment was supposed to be an answer, not a comment so I would be able to choose and vote the fair way. Thank you anyway for your great help!!!

Comment: Not a problem. Omri provided the correct answer. I wasn't sure this is what you were after so I thought better to comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

Change ng-click to:

```
ng-click="openModal(person)"
```

Inject `$modal` to the controller and define a new function:

```
app.controller('ModalDemoCtrl', function($scope, $modal) {
... 

    $scope.openModal = function (person) {
        $modal({title: person.firstName, content: person.lastName, show: true});
    }

...

}
```

Notice you need to remove `bs-modal="modal"` and the `$scope.modal = {..}` definition.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/by3rph5s/9/)